# Keep table height fixed despite of number of rows in it for ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

What I want is already here [How to scroll table's "tbody" independent of "thead"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321849/how-to-scroll-tables-tbody-independent-of-thead)

The only problem is that I can not make it work on IE9.

I have made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fe8Xf/

I am using sample table like this:

```
<table border='1px'>
<tr>
    <td>1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td><td>5</td>
</tr>
```

This works fine on Chrome and even IE10.
But not IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pixels instead of percent in height,if u use percent

Comment: I have added a fiddle for you to clarify more