# table thead fixed position with top bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a top bar that I set it to fixed position on scrolling.
Below I have a table. I would like the thead of the table to be fixed once the top bar is set to fixed, and the rows of the table should scroll behind that `thead` like [here](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu).

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fixmeTop = $(".fixme").offset().top;
  var countriesTableTop = $(".fixme").height() + 20; //20 is the margin
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
      $(".fixme").css({"position": "fixed", "top": "0", "left": "0"});
      $(".countries-table thead").css({"position": "fixed", "top": countriesTableTop});
    } else {
      $(".fixme").css("position", "static");
      $(".countries-table thead").css("position", "static");
    }
  });
});
```

css:

```
.fixme {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.countries-table {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}

.countries-table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 200
}
```

It works just fine for the top bar fixed position, but unfortunately not for the table.

See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/w89mepps/).

Please note that I don't to limit the table height. The idea is that the user will always see the thead.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321849/how-to-scroll-tables-tbody-independent-of-thead ?

Comment: yes, the table height is limited there

Comment: why must the table height not be limited? you could always use a `vh` if you don't want it to be a pixel value, and it becomes dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.fixme {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 5000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.countries-table {
    width: 382px;
    background-color: silver;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.countries-table thead tr {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    width: 383px;
}
.countries-table tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.countries-table thead tr td:nth-child(1),
.countries-table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 190px;
}
.countries-table thead tr td:nth-child(2),
.countries-table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 190px;
}
.countries-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

[CLICK HERE FOR DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/92fqynLL/1/)

Comment: You can achieved this without javascript

Comment: but the height is limited - height: 300px;

Comment: you can set height whatever you want

Comment: or you can also make dynamic height with javascript

Comment: also, the top bar doesn't scroll up as in my jsfiddle