# Scroll for the table to apply it to tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css

So for the below `table`, I am trying to apply the scroll for the `tbody`, so that the table `header` will stick. How can I achieve this? Also when I tried making the display to block for the `tbody` the alignment is breaking.

Tried with this but the alignment got broke:

```
 tbody{
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

What is the best way to achieve this and to implement horizontal scroll if the heading of columns got increased?

```css
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Total Count</th>
      <th>Total People</th>
      <th>Summary Count</th>
      <th>Manual Count</th>
      <th>Value on Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/2/ Hope this will help you find the solution , already answered in the forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321849/how-to-scroll-tables-tbody-independent-of-thead

Comment: Thanks midhun for the response, tried it but the alignment is breaking, its not having the same width as the th. Alignment is breaking thats the issue :(

Comment: There are two solution one use 2 separate table one for `header` and one for `tbody`, Second try to `stick header` inside some `div` rather then `tbody`.

Comment: @Awais can you add the snippet, because if i remove the thead and have only the tbody it is also not working

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS i added snippet of solution 1 below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td{
  word-break: break-all;
}

td,th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 130px;
  word-break: break-all;// if text length increases we need to have
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
.tbl-cover{
  position: relative;
}
.fxd-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl-cover">
<table class="fxd-header">  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Total Count</th>
      <th>Total People</th>
      <th>Summary Count</th>
      <th>Manual Count</th>
      <th>Value on Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
  <div class="tbl-inner">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1_test_test_test_test</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Some minor changes, if text length increases we need to have word-break: break-all;

Comment: Sorry! Didn't remember, Updated that in my answer.

Comment: Updated it with first column as a lengthy text

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Thanks for improving my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please view in full size you will get the solution

```css
.fixed_header{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
 
  color:#fff;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 150px;
}
table {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Total Count</th>
      <th>Total People</th>
      <th>Summary Count</th>
      <th>Manual Count</th>
      <th>Value on Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i am getting the same problem in viceversa, when the screen size is more th border line is not in proper alignment ? how can i fix it. Because alignment should be fit for every screen isn't else it will be breaking at some screens

Comment: Screesize issues are there the column is not matching with the data, borders are not align properly